# The Scala equivalent to Go's math.Nextafter

Tags: scala, go

I was wondering if Scala or one of its well known math libraries (e.g. [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire)) has an equivalent to Go's `math.Nextafter` function

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Now you have %g problems.",
        math.Nextafter(2, 3))
}
```

(From http://tour.golang.org/#4)

And if not, what is the most "Scala" way to get the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the Java `Math` library:

```
scala> java.lang.Math.nextAfter(2.0,3)
res0: Double = 2.0000000000000004
```