# Why does math.Nextafter(2,3) in Go increment by 0.0000000000000004 instead of 0.0000000000000001?

Tags: go

This was taken from here: http://tour.golang.org/#5

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Now you have %g problems.",
        math.Nextafter(2, 3))
}
```

Result:

```
//Now you have 2.0000000000000004 problems.
//Program exited.
```

Comment: I guess because `2.0000000000000001` can't be represented as a 64 bit floating point number. https://golang.org/src/pkg/math/nextafter.go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have the [very same result with java/scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792703/6309).
The [`math/#Nextafter`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Nextafter) function "returns the next representable value after x towards y."

```
Float64frombits(Float64bits(x) + 1)
```

As mentioned in [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.go.general/108836)

> A float64 [cannot express all 16 digit numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding).
>   For example, if x = 0.12345678901234567, using `math.Nextafter`, you can see that the nearby float64 values are ...1234565, ...1234566 and ...1234568

See also "[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089018/6309)".
Or this thread:

> Some numbers that are exactly representable in base 10 are not exactly representable in base 2.
>   For example, the number 0.1 (base 10) can't be exactly represented in base 2.
>   Just like 0.1 (base 3) can't be exactly represented as a decimal value in base 10: it's 0.33333 (repeats forever).

The [golang issue 4398](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4398) illustrates:

```
const x1 = 1 - float64(1.00000000000000000001) // 0!
```

> [The spec says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) that a constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` if "`x` is representable by a value of type `T`."
>   The value `1.00000000000000000001` is not representable in `float64`; the closest approximation is 1.