# GoLang nextafter & %g?

Tags: go

I'm just going through tutorials of GoLang because I'm curious to learn a more general language (only know javascript).  [Tut](http://tour.golang.org/#5)

I dont understand whats happening with %g and `math.Nextafter` means?  After reviewing the documentation it helps little.

**Question:** 
Could anyone give me a better overview of the `%g` syntax and `nextafter()` method; perhaps a digestible usecase??  Here's links to documentation:[fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) //  [nextAfter](https://golang.org/src/pkg/math/nextafter.go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Now you have %G problems.",
        math.Nextafter(2, 3))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the %g syntax, see [fmt syntax](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

```
%g  whichever of %e or %f produces more compact output
%e  scientific notation, e.g. -1234.456e+78
%f  decimal point but no exponent, e.g. 123.456
```

The `float64` returned by [`NextAfter()`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Nextafter) will be presented using the scientific notation or decimal point, depending on which is more compact.

For the returned value of NextAfter, see "[Why does math.Nextafter(2,3) in Go increment by 0.0000000000000004 instead of 0.0000000000000001?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25821661/6309)"

You will see plenty of Go string formatting in "[Go by Example: String Formatting](https://gobyexample.com/string-formatting)": one parameter for the format, one for the value to be formatted.
Those formats ("verb") are listed in [`pkg/fmt/](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

Comment: why does the printf function take two parameters?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: Read the documentation for printf.

Comment: Yeah I will.  There's just a ton of things outside my realm of understanding.  For instance types float64.  I'll just read more.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood `float64` is a sixty-four bit floating-point number.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format